# What is the correct way to return a value from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, directive

I have the following set up as a directive in my angular project:

```
{
    restrict: "AE",
    replace: true,
    template: template,
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        chosen: "=ngModel",
        choices: "=choices",
        placeholder: "@placeholder"
    }
}
```

I have everything working internally for my directive, the missing piece right now is that when I select a value inside of it, the parent scope containing my directive isn't receiving any kind of update.  Despite me making assigments to `chosen` from anywhere inside of my directive.

As the title states, what's the simplest way for me to assign a value chosen inside of my directive, to it's parent's scope?

Ideally I'd like the solution to:

- Not require me to use the `link` function - I feel like this can be done declaratively
- Not require my directive to guess anything about it's parent scope

As a followup question, is there any reason to use `ngModel` in this circumstance?  Is it or could it be beneficial?  Or could I just as easily get away with recycling a `name` attribute which contains the parent scope's desired return value?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `=ngModel` as your directive attr? I'm not sure exactly sure what this will do, but I don't think it is wise. Use `=chosen` instead, and do something like this in the markup `<div my-directive="" chosen="someControllerVar"></div>`

Comment: Well, I'm wondering if there's any functionality that ngModel that I want? But I think my last paragraph eludes to what you just said.

Comment: ng-model is used for linking input values to controller scope variables. If you are building a directive that is template only, you might want to look at ng-include instead. Not really sure of what you are trying to do though, so provide more info if you can.

Comment: My directive intends to behave like an input.  It's a custom `select` element basically.